# Do volatile writes flush also non-volatile writes?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I am split. Brian Goetz's article https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html says that the double locking pattern is broken even when you use volatile

```
class SomeClass {
  private volatile Resource resource = null;
  public Resource getResource() {
    if (resource == null) {
      synchronized {
        if (resource == null) 
          resource = new Resource();
      }
    }
    return resource;
  }
}
```

He says that

> JMM [...] permits reads and writes of volatile variables to be reordered with respect to nonvolatile reads and writes. That means -- unless all Resource fields are volatile as well -- thread B can still perceive the constructor's effect as happening after resource is set to reference the newly created Resource.

But everything else says this is not true. First, the JMM that there is a happens-before relationship between 2 actions in the same thread (in this case the call to the resource constructor and the assignment to the resource variable) AND there is also a happens-before relationship between the write to a volatile and subsequent reads to that volatile. This means that what he said in that article is not possible.

Second, all resources on the web (including this article https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html signed by Joshua Bloch) say that volatile is a valid fix.

If this article on JW was written by any other person except the author of Java Concurrency in Practice I would have ignored it. But I can't.

Comment: That article is way outdated. The happens-before relationships were introduced in later versions of Java. Still, while volatile now enables the double lock antipattern to produce the intended results, it's still an antipattern. Just get the resource when you declare it. If you had no intention to have this resource you wouldn't have code to provide it.

Comment: The Goetz article was written in 2001, and it is talking about the Java spec current at that time (i.e. the 2nd edition: http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0.pdf).  What Goetz says is correct for versions of Java available at the time. The problem was fixed in the third edition (Java 6) in 2006.

Comment: I just realised this myself. Did not know volatile meaning changed between Java versions

Comment: You can take a look at this good post: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/